# Solve this Integral Without a Calculator

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I was reading this question in my textbook. It doesn't say it requires a calculator which makes me think it doesn't. I can't figure it out, and I was wondering if there was a trick to doing it.

Find the area of the region enclosed by the $y-$axis and the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=(x^2+x+1)e^{-x}$.

The second equation is above $y=x^2$ because when $x=0\implies y=(x^2+x+1)e^{-x}=1$.

> The question is when do these functions intersect?

> $x^2=(x^2+x+1)e^{-x}\implies 0=x^2e^{-x}+xe^{-x}+e^{-x}-x^2\implies \text{Don't Know Where to Go From Here...}$

Comment: I don't think there's a nice answer for this...

Comment: Maple isn't able to find a closed-form solution for $x$ at the point of intersection, so it's unlikely that you'll be able to find one. Numerically it's about 1.05032.

Comment: I don't think there is one either :(

Comment: My guess is that it is a typo and the first curve was meant to be $y=x^2\,e^{-x}$.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: p. 351 number 34 of this book here: https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Graphical-Numerical-Algebraic-Hardcover/dp/B014S2MV6Q

Comment: @MartinArgerami I thought the same thing! I mean that would have been perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

Let me suppose that there is not typo and that we want to compute
$$I=\int_0^t \Big[(x^2+x+1)e^{-x}-x^2 \Big]\,dx=4-\frac{t^3}{3}- e^{-t} \left( t^2+3 t+4\right)$$ $t$ being the value of $x$ such that
$$(x^2+x+1)e^{-x}=x^2$$

There is a formal definition since we can write
$$e^{-x}=\frac {(x-0)(x-0)}{(x-a)(x-b)}$$ where $(a,b)$ are the roots of the quadratic. Then the solution is given in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equations $(4)$ and $(5)$).

This is  formally nice but not very practical.

Knowing (by inspection or graphing) that $t$ is just above $1$, make
$$f(x)=(x^2+x+1)e^{-x}-x^2=$$ $$\left(\frac{3}{e}-1\right)-2 (x-1)-\left(1+\frac{1}{2 e}\right)   (x-1)^2+\frac 1e\sum_{n=4}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(n-3) (n-1)}{n!}(x-1)^n$$ Neglecting the summation
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{3}{e}-1\right)-2 (x-1)-\left(1+\frac{1}{2 e}\right)   (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$
and using series reversion, we have the approximation
$$x=1+y-\frac{(1+2 e) }{4 e}y^2+\frac{(1+2 e)^2}{8 e^2} y^3+O\left(y^{4}\right)$$ where $y=-\frac{1}{2} \left(f(x)-\frac{3}{e}+1\right)$. Making $f(x)=0$ as desired, then the approximation of $t$.

Using my phone, $t\sim 1.05$ (using a computer $t=1.05033$, the "exact" solution being $t=1.05032$).Still without computer make $t\sim\frac{21}{20}$  to make (still with my phone)
$$I \sim \frac{28913}{8000}-\frac{3301}{400e}e^{-1/20}$$

Now, using $e\sim \frac{19}{7}$ and $e^{-1/20}\sim 1-\frac 1 {20}=\frac{19}{20}$ then
$$I \sim \frac{28913}{8000}-\frac{3301}{400}\times \frac7{19}\times\frac{19}{20}=\frac{2903}{4000}=0.72575$$

while the "exact" solution (using Newton method to compute $t$) would be $0.72626$. That is to say that we have an absolute relative error equal to $0.07$%.